# How do I calibrate more than two cameras, mounted on the same plane?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, camera-calibration

I have four cameras, mounted on a steel plate in a square pattern (two rows of two). I would like to calibrate these cameras to determine the intrinsic parameters, and the relative positions of the camera. I can obtain the intrinsic parameters using openCV's calibrateCamera.

Typically I would use stereoCalibrate for calibration of two cameras. I could do the same here, but I would prefer a more scalable solution.

My question is, how do I stereoCalibrate more that two cameras, with the known constraint that they are all mounted on the same plane? One option is to solvePnP, but this ignores the planar constraint.